# Some online video players doesn't work

Tags: flash, mozilla

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.04. And faced the following problem: youtube player works pretty fine, but [this one](https://www.amediateka.ru/serial/igra-prestolov/1/1) doesn't. I've installed actual version of Flash Player and refreshed Mozilla settings. The same problem with Chromium. What might be wrong?

**EDIT:** btw Google Chrome works well.

Comment: It tells me that the service is not available in my country (USA)

Comment: Well, think that is just some other player. Or tell me how can i provide some information about it.

Comment: No, the website is pretty clear  "Due to license restrictions Amediateka is available only on the territory of Russian Federation, Kazakhstan, Uzbekistan, Turkmenistan, Azerbaijan, Tajikistan, Armenia and Belarus."

Comment: That's true. I've come here straight from the Russia. Believe me that this player doesn't work. How can i edit my question to make it more clear?

Comment: How did you install Flash Player?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Comment: [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) page tells that everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Well, `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is not sufficient for Firefox. The recommended way for Ubuntu users to install Flash is to enable Canonical Partners and install the `adobe-flashplugin` package. That way you get Flash for both Firefox and Chromium, and Flash will be updated via the regular package updates (which is not the case with `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`).

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Possibly (since I'm not in Russia I can't test) it makes a difference in Firefox to also install the `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` package.

Comment: I installed both of the packages and this player doesn't work still. It works in chrome, random flash player games work in Mozilla. So, more likely, the problem isn't caused by Flash Player. Possibly some Mozilla bug?? Here is a block of this video player that is important I guess (I don't know how do online video players work): `<video id="mediaItemPlayer_Shaka_api" class="vjs-tech" src="blob:https://www.amediateka.ru/21918df1-b089-4b1a-a2a4-1a135c4feebe" autoplay=""></video>`

Comment: @Александр: Ok, that's what I'm able to come up with. I'm afraid I can't interpret that markup code. Hopefully someone else can do better.